# Why sending one PDF by email results in an "Invoked too many times" error in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation

Sending this PDF as an attachment is resulting in this error: `Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.` and I can't see why.

```
function emailSavePo(poNumber, supplier, unit) {
  poNumber = '2B'
  supplier = 'ABC'
  unit = 'UnitA'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var pdfName = 'PO' + ' ' + poNumber + ' - ' + supplier + ' - ' + unit;
  var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName('PO Sheet').getSheetId();
  
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
    + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
    // following parameters are optional...
    + '&size=A4'      // paper size
    + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
    + '&top_margin=0.50'
    + '&bottom_margin=0.50'
    + '&left_margin=0.50'
    + '&right_margin=0.50'
    + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
    + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
    + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    const mailOptions = {
      attachments: blob
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email,
      subject + " " + pdfName + "",
      "Hello! \n\nHere is a copy of the PO! \n\nBest regards,\nTeam",
      mailOptions);
    ss.toast('A pdf copy of the PO has been sent to ' + email + '!')
  }
}
```

Logged all parts of it and it all seems OK.

Comment: How many times was urlfetch called in the past 24 hours in this script and other secret scripts?

Comment: Any custom functions in another spreadsheet elsewhere?

Comment: There are but unrelated and no urlfetchapp.  @TheMaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to consider other functions that you may have on other spreadsheets. The quota limit for URL fetch calls is 20,000 per day on a personal Gmail account and   100,000 per day on a business Google Workspace account. This quota count towards your Google account, it's possible that other functions on your account are consuming your quota. Try running the script on a different account, if it works that means that something is consuming your quota. You can check the details about quotas for Google services using this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Great that you've joined! Thanks! I've actually seen the same issue when running a function in another file, so it may really be it. I think that there are methods to get the current quota and back the error with how many calls we got left.